# Is it possible to calculate Lucas numbers recursively with time complexity O(n)?

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

I have a [homework assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqt9Q.png) to calculate Lucas numbers. How can I make my algorithm O(n) while still keeping it recursive?

This is the hint he gives:

[image]

When thinking about the question I thought I would keep my main for loop and make it so that it stores the 2 numbers before the one computed but then that would be iterative.

This is my code right now:

```
lucas(n) {  
    return 2 if n = 0;
    return 1 if n = 1;
    return lucas(n - 1) + lucas(n - 2);
}
main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++)
        print(lucas(i*5));
}
```

(The code is written like that in case of plagiarism.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I will not post the solution as code, but I hope I can show the path to it.

The given hint uses a vector with 2 values - in Java we can use an array (since a method cannot return just two values).  The method needs the value of `n`.

```java
int[] calc(int n) {
    // TODO
}
```

The formula `Gn = M X Gn-1` - `M` is the given matrix, and `Gn = [An , Bn]` (`An = Ln` and `Bn = Ln-1`) - can we rewritten as
`[An , Bn] = [[1,1] [1,0]] X [An-1 , Bn-1]` or

`An = 1*An-1 + 1*Bn-1 = An-1 + Bn-1` and
`Bn = 1*An-1 + 0*Bn-1 = An-1`

The method would call itself with `n-1`, unless `n == 0`, to get `[An-1,Bn-1]` and then calculate the output array `[An,Bn]` using above formula.

Initial array, for `n=0`, should be `[2,-1]` (aka `G0` in hint.)

(since `Gn` only depends on `Gn-1` the *pure* recursive solution is `O(n)` - unlike the usual method to calculate the Lucas number where `Ln` depends on `Ln-1` and `Ln-2`)

---

I have completely ignored the second hint and used `int[]` above - but don't forget to consider if an `int` will be able to represent `L500`
(having the hint is a sign that it will not)

Comment: Thanks. I used your path and I got it to work. I would upvote but I am a new user and can't. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think a Memoized solution for this problem will be O(n) because each solution for `n` will be calculated no more than one time.

The "trick" is to store the results of `lucas(n)` in a map so that previously calculated results will be retrieved in constant time O(1) and new values will be calculated once.

(**Complete solution needs to compute only if value is not in map**)

```
public class MemoizedLucas {
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // add base cases to map
        results.put(0, 2);
        results.put(1, 1);

        // compute lucas number
        lucas(10);
        System.out.println(results);
    }
    // The lucas function will be called at most 2*n times - O(2*n) is still considered liner time. 
    public static int lucas(int n) {
        
        Integer result = results.get(n);
        if (result != null) return result; // return value if in map

        int a = lucas(n - 1);
        int b = lucas (n - 2);
        results.put(n , a + b);
        return results.get(n);
    }
}
```

If printed out, the first 10 numbers of the sequence outputted by this program are:

`2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123`

Comment: @user16320675 you are right. I meant to put the complete solution but decided not to (and kept the "complete solution" label). Should I remove the label and let the OP complete the code based on my explanation or should I simply complete the solution?

Comment: @user16320675 I think you missed the point of my answer. The "completeness" of my answer was regarding not being _0(n)_. It is now. The solution now looks up already calculated answers. Therefore, it is _O(1) + O(2*N)_ which is reduced to _O(n)_.

Comment: @user16320675 no worries!

Comment: only if value is not in map would be iterative, no? Thank you anyway I used the path by user16320675 and got it!

Comment: Yes, when value is not in map, it will be recursive. When it is in map, it's an "instant" lookup which is constant time or O(1). The other part is O(2*N) because you make at most two recursive calls. O(2*N) is considered linear time.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is to define a recursive G function, and take on of both Lucas values for the G result. The lucas function can then be defined as call to G.

As you see, G is O(N).

```
int lucas(int n) { return g(n)[0]; }
int[] g(int n) { ... recursiveG ... }
```

Comment: I now see how  G is O(N) thanks